# Problem with two functions working together to create plots with equally spaced marks

Tags: pgfplots, pgfkeys

I'm using:

```
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.markings}

    \makeatletter
    \tikzset{
      nomorepostactions/.code={\let\tikz@postactions=\pgfutil@empty},
      mymark/.style 2 args={decoration={markings,
        mark= between positions 0 and 1 step (1/11)*\pgfdecoratedpathlength with{%
            \tikzset{#2,every mark}\tikz@options
            \pgfuseplotmark{#1}%
          },  
        },
        postaction={decorate},
        /pgfplots/legend image post style={
            mark=#1,mark options={#2},every path/.append style={nomorepostactions}
        },
      },
    }
    \makeatother

    \pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{my black white}{%
    solid, every mark/.append style={solid, fill=gray}, mymark=*\\%
    dotted, every mark/.append style={solid, fill=gray},mymark=square*\\%
    densely dotted, every mark/.append style={solid, fill=gray}, mymark=otimes*\\%
    loosely dotted, every mark/.append style={solid, fill=gray}, mymark=triangle*\\%
    dashed, every mark/.append style={solid, fill=gray},mark=diamond*\\%
    loosely dashed, every mark/.append style={solid, fill=gray},mark=*\\%
    densely dashed, every mark/.append style={solid, fill=gray},mymark=square*\\%
    dashdotted, every mark/.append style={solid, fill=gray},mark=otimes*\\%
    dasdotdotted, every mark/.append style={solid},mymark=star\\%
    densely dashdotted,every mark/.append style={solid, fill=gray},mark=diamond*\\%
    }

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]

\begin{axis}[%
width=4.432in,
height=3.031in,
at={(0.743in,0.409in)},
scale only axis,
xmode=log,
legend style={legend cell align=left,align=left,draw=white!15!black},
xmin=0,
grid style = {dashed, black!15!white},
minor grid style = {dashed, black!15!white},
major grid style = {dashed, black!15!white},
cycle list name=my black white,
xlabel = {$x$},
ylabel = {$f(x)$},
xmax=10000,
xminorticks=true,
ymin=0,
grid=both,
ymax=10,
axis background/.style={fill=white}
]
\addplot% [color=mycolor1]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
0    0\\
1    2\\
2    4\\
3    6\\
10    5\\
100    4\\
1000    1\\
500    4\\
};
\addlegendentry{Failing};
```

To cycle through plot line/mark styles and also ensure that all of the marks are spaced at an equal distance from one another along the path of the plot. It works fine for a single plot, but when I try to do it for multiple plots, it fails. Can somebody help me fix it? It is important to get equally spaced marks when using xlog, otherwise they bunch up toward higher values (unless you've done a logarithmic sweep by points, which isn't always available on some instruments).

I get the following error:

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/quare*' and I am going to
 ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.3641 \end{axis}
```

Where the first letter of the mark type is cut off: `Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/quare*' and I a...` (no `s`).

---

So, with the below advice the `my black white` function becomes:

```
\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{my black white}{%
mymark={*}{solid, fill=gray}\\%
mymark={square*}{solid, fill=gray}\\%
mymark={otimes*}{solid, fill=gray}\\%
%loosely dotted, every mark/.append style={solid, fill=gray}, mymark=triangle*\\%
%dashed, every mark/.append style={solid, fill=gray},mark=diamond*\\%
%loosely dashed, every mark/.append style={solid, fill=gray},mark=*\\%
%densely dashed, every mark/.append style={solid, fill=gray},mymark=square*\\%
%dashdotted, every mark/.append style={solid, fill=gray},mark=otimes*\\%
%dasdotdotted, every mark/.append style={solid},mymark=star\\%
%densely dashdotted,every mark/.append style={solid, fill=gray},mark=diamond*\\%
}
```

Comment: Well, you defined `mymark` as a `style 2 args`, which means that you must give it two arguments: `mymark={arg1}{arg2}`. Judging by your code, `arg1` should be the mark name, and `arg2` any options for the mark.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. the functions aren't mine, and I'm not very adept with that kind of code... How would I go about fixing it?

Comment: `mymark={square*}{}` does work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a style is defined like

```
mymark/.style 2 args={...}
```

it means that the style takes two mandatory arguments, and should be used as

```
mymark={argument 1}{argument 2}.
```

In your usage of `mymark`, you've written e.g. `mymark=square*`, so what it looks like is happening, is that TikZ grabs `s` as the first argument, and for some reason `quare*` as the second. I don't know exactly why it doesn't fail for the first line.

In the definition of `mymark`, as in the definition of macros, `#1` represents the first argument, and `#2` the second. So you can see, if you look at the code, that `#1` should be a marker type, and `#2` options for that mark (e.g. color and size). That should be evident from

```
mark=#1,mark options={#2}
```

Now, you can leave the second argument empty, but it has to be there, so if you don't need to fine tune the look of the marker, you can change

```
mymark=square*
```

to

```
mymark={square*}{solid,fill=gray}
```

and similarly for all the other instances of `mymark`. Then remove `every mark/.append style={solid, fill=gray}` from every style in the cycle list.

Complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.markings}

    \makeatletter
    \tikzset{
      nomorepostactions/.code={\let\tikz@postactions=\pgfutil@empty},
      mymark/.style 2 args={decoration={markings,
        mark= between positions 0 and 1 step (1/11)*\pgfdecoratedpathlength with{%
            \tikzset{#2,every mark}\tikz@options
            \pgfuseplotmark{#1}%
          },  
        },
        postaction={decorate},
        /pgfplots/legend image post style={
            mark=#1,mark options={#2},every path/.append style={nomorepostactions}
        },
      },
    }
    \makeatother

    \pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{my black white}{%
    solid, mymark={*}{solid, fill=gray}\\%
    dotted, mymark={square*}{solid, fill=gray}\\%
    densely dotted, mymark={otimes*}{solid, fill=gray}\\%
    loosely dotted, mymark={triangle*}{solid, fill=gray}\\%
    dashed, mymark={diamond*}{solid, fill=gray}\\%
    loosely dashed, mymark={*}{solid, fill=gray}\\%
    densely dashed, mymark={square*}{solid, fill=gray}\\%
    dashdotted,mymark={otimes*}{solid, fill=gray}\\%
    dasdotdotted, mymark={star}{solid, }\\%
    densely dashdotted,mark={diamond*}{solid, fill=gray}\\%
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
width=4.432in,
height=3.031in,
at={(0.743in,0.409in)},
scale only axis,
xmode=log,
legend style={legend cell align=left,align=left,draw=white!15!black},
xmin=0,
grid style = {dashed, black!15!white},
minor grid style = {dashed, black!15!white},
major grid style = {dashed, black!15!white},
cycle list name=my black white,
xlabel = {$x$},
ylabel = {$f(x)$},
xmax=10000,
xminorticks=true,
ymin=0,
grid=both,
ymax=10,
axis background/.style={fill=white}
]
\addplot% [color=mycolor1]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
0    0\\
1    2\\
2    4\\
3    6\\
10    5\\
100    4\\
1000    1\\
5000    4\\
};
\addplot% [color=mycolor1]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
0    1\\
1    3\\
2    4\\
3    6\\
10    6\\
100    5\\
1000    2\\
5000    5\\
};
\addplot% [color=mycolor1]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
0    2\\
1    4\\
2    6\\
3    8\\
10    7\\
100    5\\
1000    3\\
5000    6\\
};
\addlegendentry{Failing};
\addlegendentry{Failing2};
\addlegendentry{Failing3};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @lmsavk Did it work though?

Comment: Just appending {} didn't work, but wrapping the line style in {} and appending that instead, did work. As in the edited original post. 
Thanks again.

Comment: @lmsavk Ah, I hadn't noticed the `every mark` setting. I'd guess, again without having tested, that you could/should do `mymark={*}{solid,fill=gray}`. Do you actually want the linestyles (e.g. `densely dotted`) in the `mark options`?

Comment: Yes, that's true - I've just noticed it. I do need dotted, densely dotted, etc... Do I need to add a 3rd argument? I should also note that the correct colour of the mark fill is not correctly displayed in the legend.

Comment: @lmsavk No, you need to keep `densely dotted` etc. outside of the `mymark` altogether. The `mymark` style is *just* for defining the markers, linestyles are separate. I added an example to my answer, which seems to work just fine.